# How can i install 'WinDev2307Eval.VirtualBox' downloaded in download folder of my desktop 22.04.2?

Tags: software-installation

I WANT TO INSTALL MS ENGLISH FONTS. HAVE DOWNLOADED VIRTUALBOX.ZIP AND EXTRACTED THE FILE "WinDev2307Eval.VirtualBox" I do not know what to write in the command to recognise the file in DOWNLOAD folder.